# UPS WorldShip XML IMPORT to Puerto Rico

Tags: xml, ups

im having a lot of trouble with UPS world ship creating a label to Puerto Rico.

I have tried adding different international documentation fields but have had no luck.

Does anyone have working international example?

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<OpenShipments xmlns="x-schema:OpenShipments.xdr">

<OpenShipment ProcessStatus="" ShipmentOption="">

<ShipTo>
<CompanyOrName>xxx</CompanyOrName>
<Attention>xxx</Attention>
<Address1>xxx</Address1>
<Address2>xxx</Address2> 
<PostalCode>00959</PostalCode>
<CityOrTown>Bayamon</CityOrTown>
<CountryTerritory>PR</CountryTerritory>
<StateProvinceCounty>PR</StateProvinceCounty>
<Telephone>xxx</Telephone>
</ShipTo>

<ShipFrom>
<CompanyOrName>xxx</CompanyOrName>
<Address1>xxx</Address1> 
<PostalCode>xx</PostalCode>
<CityOrTown>xx</CityOrTown> 
<StateProvinceCounty>xx</StateProvinceCounty>
<CountryTerritory>US</CountryTerritory>
<Telephone>xxx</Telephone>
</ShipFrom>


<ShipmentInformation>
<ServiceType>GND</ServiceType>

</ShipmentInformation>

<Package>
<PackageType>CP</PackageType>
<Weight>1</Weight>


</Package>  


</OpenShipment>
</OpenShipments>
```

im getting error:

```
Error on line 58, Element content is invalid according to the DTD/Schema.
Expecting: {x-schema:OpenShipments.xdr}CreateAnInvoice, {x-schema:OpenShipments.xdr}InvoiceImporterSameAsShipTo, {x-schema:OpenShipment....
```

Comment: where is the schema for UPS xml ? Do you have a reference to it?

Comment: here is xls doc i found. but  I think im only missing a few requred feilds.. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj69teb__XOAhVB0h4KHX0WBWIQFgglMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ups.com%2Fmedia%2Fen%2FXML_File_Spec.xls&usg=AFQjCNFM91HBW6gXX5CYzWDWun7OR4yMzQ